# Correlation Study to Determine Weights Of Fields

Tags: python, regression, correlation

I have several input fields, and the content for each field can either be correct or incorrect. These fields are then sent to a black-boxed function (which I can’t control), and the output of the function can either be correct or incorrect.

I want to do a regression study to determine how influential the correctness of each of the fields is in the correctness of the result, and then assign weights to each of the fields based on the study to maximize correctness of the output.

I have done simple studies of correlation between two variables before but do not know how to approach this problem. Could you give me some direction of the steps I would need to take? Once I have them, I can figure out how to do each. I work in Python.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: correlation requires continous variables, instead try accuracy scores

Comment: @Nikos M. - If necessary, I can measure the level of “correctness” with a number between 0 and 1, both for input and output.